# can I install laravel echo server without npm

Tags: laravel, websocket, socket.io, laravel-echo

hi guys I faced some problems when I install laravel echo serve so I decided to download the source and place him in npm location as you expected it doesn't work .
my question is is there a way to install laravel ech with out npm yarn etc..
I mean from the source.

Comment: You should fix the problems you encountered instead of trying to do a hacky workaround.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. Laravel echo is a server running on NodeJS, using npm to meet it's package requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Works in the browser
`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/laravel-echo@1.6.1/dist/echo.iife.js"></script>`

add the echo script to your page
https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/laravel-echo

From 
https://martincarlin.uk/2017/04/26/how-to-use/